# how to get google analytics report api ga4 for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client

i have installed a google analytics ga4 in my mobile app now i need to fetch the GA report into node.js using google analytics report api.

i have read the google analytics report document but the did'nt mentioned about how to get reoprt for
node.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example for extracting data from Google analytics ga4 with node.js

```
// npm install googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0 --save
// npm install @google-analytics/data

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'];

const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\ServiceAccountCred.json';

/**
 * Runs a Google Analytics report
 * For a given property id
 */
async function runReport(propertyId) {

    // Imports the Google Analytics Data API client library.
    const {BetaAnalyticsDataClient} = require('@google-analytics/data');
    // Load the credentials.
    const content = fs.readFileSync(CREDENTIALS_PATH, {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient(
        { credentials: keys}
    );

    // Runs a simple report.
    async function runReport() {
            const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
                property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
                dateRanges: [
                    {
                        startDate: '2020-03-31',
                        endDate: 'today',
                    },
                ],
                dimensions: [
                    {
                        name: 'city',
                    },
                ],
                metrics: [
                    {
                        name: 'activeUsers',
                    },
                ],
            });

            console.log('Report result:');
            response.rows.forEach(row => {
                console.log(row.dimensionValues[0], row.metricValues[0]);
            });
        }

    await runReport();
}

runReport('250796939').then().catch(console.error);
```